# checkmarx scan issue that password variable is never cleared from memory

Tags: properties, passwords, checkmarx

> Password, which is designated to contain user passwords. However, while plaintext passwords are later assigned to Password, this variable is never cleared from memory.

I have a class with Password property and I am getting above error from Checkmarx scan report.

Please help me how to resolve this error.

Comment: I think you need to delete the value of the `Password` property by reassign and calling to the garbage collector. But we need more details.

Answer (score 1):

Use SecureString, it implements IDisposable Interface. In my case, I created an extension for SecureString.

```
 public static class SecureStringExtension
    {
        public static string ToUnsecureString(this SecureString source)
        {
            var returnValue = IntPtr.Zero;
            try
            {
                returnValue = Marshal.SecureStringToGlobalAllocUnicode(source);
                
                return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(returnValue);
            }
            finally
            {
                Marshal.ZeroFreeGlobalAllocUnicode(returnValue);
            }
        }

        public static SecureString ToSecureString(this string source)
        {

            SecureString password = new SecureString();

            foreach (char c in source)
            {
                password.AppendChar(c);
            }

            password.MakeReadOnly();

            return password;
        }
    }
```

Usage :

```
SecureString password = "P@SSword".ToSecureString();
 ////// business logic here
//////
password.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to clear a Password value, is to rewrite with random content the value, and after this, deleted it. This unsure that the old value are not in place anywhere in memory.